# Redirecting to the wrong route when submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, laravel, routes

I am submitting my login form and define the route action="{{route('signin')}}" but it is redirecting the user to the login route.

form code is here .

```
<form  action="{{route('signin')}}" method="post" role="form">

                   <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                       <label>Enter Email : </label>

                           <input placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('email')}}">
                           @if ($errors->has('email'))
                               <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                           @endif

                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label>Enter  Password :</label>
                        <input placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="{{Request::old('password')}}">
                           @if ($errors->has('password'))
                               <span class="help-block">
                                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                            </span>
                           @endif

                    </div>

                {{csrf_field()}}
                    <input class="btn btn-outline btn-danger" type="submit" value="submit" title="Login">


            </form>
```

Code in routes is here .

```
 Route::get('/login',[
    'uses' => 'userController@user',
    'as' => 'login'
]);
 Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' => 'userController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin',
    'middleware'=>'auth',
]);
```

Comment: i dont see the form start tag in de code

Comment: ok let me update my question.

Comment: Remove the "middleware" from your signin route. It redirects you before you actually enter the method.

Comment: @Alex, not anyone sees the comments before answer. so, if you sure of your answer, put it as answer not comment

Comment: hm, I'm sure @RaymondNijland saw it .. as he answered before here.. but ye. I will make it an answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::post('/signin',[
    'uses' => 'userController@postSignIn',
    'as' => 'signin'
]);
```

Just remove the "auth" middleware as it doesnt allow access to the method before sign in.

Answer (score 2):

change post route to this:

```
Route::post('/signin',[
  'uses' => 'userController@postSignIn',
  'as' => 'signin',
]);
```

Comment: sorry didn't see the comment. remove answer?